# how to find hourly time difference all record from sql table in oracle 11g?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I want to select all entries from the table named carpooling where time difference between ends_on and start_on is 1 hour can someone help me in writing query with explanation? i have attached images in links below.

[table reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5dIo.jpg)

[click here for query reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhyUW.jpg)

Comment: 1. You have added too many tags that are simply not possible. What is your database ? Oracle ? SqlServer ? MySQL ? Remove the tags that are not correct.
2. Add the code you have tried so far and that you have problems with...
3. Do not add images of your tables and so on... That is not a good way to do it. Instead of that you can add it to some fiddle or like text... Image is the worst option...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, converts timestamp to date and substracts on day basis

```
  select *
  from carpooling
  where trunc(cast(ends_on as date),'mi')-trunc(cast(start_on as date),'mi')=1/24
```

Comment: inconsistent datatypes: expected INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND got NUMBER I got this error

Comment: I edited the my code try now.

Comment: not still working

Comment: select * from carpooling where to_char(ends_on-start_on,'hh')='01'; my friend suggested me this but still im getting no results

Comment: Can u check what is the datatype of your ends_on and start_on column?

Comment: its timestamp for both ends_on and start_on

Comment: Well that makes a big difference ok I will update my code

Comment: Now it should work!

Comment: its working but we need to find time in hour:minutes format can you do this pls??

Comment: I updated it now it searches for exactly 1 hour difference

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: Yes its working thanks 